# Como imprimir desde el lado del cliente con java

Tags: java, netbeans, jsp

Tengo una aplicación web corriendo en un servidor xampp, en windows 10 (mysql, apache y tomcat), 2 pcs como clientes del servicio todo bien asta la hora de imprimir, pues me manda el imprimir en el pc que hace de servidor web y no en los clientes, he estado investigando pero no hay mucha información al respecto dejo el código que estoy utilizando para la impresión.

```
    public void print() {
   

    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
    
    PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    PrintService printService[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, pras);
    PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    PrintService service = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 700, 200, printService, defaultService, flavor, pras);
    
     
    byte[] bytes;
    bytes = this.contentTicket.getBytes();
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes,flavor,null);

    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();


    try {
      
      job.print(doc, null);
    } catch (PrintException er) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error al imprimir: " + er.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Cómo está hecha la interfaz? Pusiste la etiqueta [tag:jsp] pero pareciera Swing. Una vez esté claro qué ve el cliente, será más fácil que recibas sugerencias. PD. Para qué usas xampp y tomcat a la vez?

Comment: La vista jsp, recojo los datos con jquery y con servlet mando llamar al metodo print, xampp tiene el servicio de tomcat incluido.